# Content Block throws CSP error

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-security-policy

We have a Content Block that we built with https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/blocksdk.

Since the last update we get this error message when opening the CB in the Email Editor:

> [Report Only] Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' *.exacttarget.com *.marketingcloudapps.com *.marketingclouddevapps.com *.marketingcloudqaapps.com *.marketingcloudtestapps.com *.marketingcloudstageapps.com *.marketingcloudapps.local *.marketingcloudapps.local.sfdc.net *.local.sfdc.net *.exct.net *.salesforce.com *.aws-dev2-uswest2.aws.sfdc.cl *.sfmc-content.com localhost:3000". ```

In adition we also get this error message wich leads to our CB failing:

> [Report Only] Refused to connect to 'https://app.igodigital.com/api/v2/organization/XXXXXXXX/item_types?api_key=d570a00e-3a74-403f-b804-XXXXXXXXXXX' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback. ```

Did MCL change its CSP Policy in the last update that we get these errors?